# How to optimize repetitive exists and non exists clauses in sql stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored proc where I have the same 'not exists' clause repeated. Every 'not exists' clause in every select is repeated in the subsequent select queries and the 'exist' clause becomes 'non exist' in the subsequent select queries.
Is there way I can do each 'non exists' and 'exists' only once and save those results and use them across the proc? What is the optimized way for this?
Thank you!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCaseType] 
@ID numeric(18,0)
AS

BEGIN                   
SET NOCOUNT ON;    
DECLARE @cnt int;

SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) 
            FROM tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK) 
            join tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK)  on cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
            join tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK)  on ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
            WHERE ct.Type in ('AG', 'PH')
            and 
            not exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                        join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                        WHERE ca.Code in ('Z', 'W')
                        and ch.ID = @ID)
            and
            c.ID = @ID

IF (@cnt > 1)
    RETURN 'CATEGORY 1'

SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) 
            FROM tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK) 
            join tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK)  on cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
            join tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK)  on ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
            WHERE ct.Type in ('AG', 'PH')
            and 
            not exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                        join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                        WHERE ca.Code in ('Z', 'W')
                        and ch.ID = @ID)
            and
            exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                    join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                    WHERE ca.Code in ('N', 'O')
                    and ch.ID = @ID)
            and
            c.ID = @ID

IF (@cnt > 1)
    RETURN 'CATEGORY 2'

SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) 
        FROM tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK) 
        join tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK)  on cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
        join tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK)  on ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
        WHERE ct.Type in ('AG', 'PH')
        and 
        not exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                    join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                    WHERE ca.Code in ('Z', 'W')
                    and ch.ID = @ID)
        and
        not exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                WHERE ca.Code in ('N', 'O')
                and ch.ID = @ID)
        and
        exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                WHERE ca.Code in ('D', 'B')
                and ch.ID = @ID)
        and
        c.ID = @ID

IF (@cnt > 1)
    RETURN 'CATEGORY 2'


SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) 
        FROM tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK) 
        join tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK)  on cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
        join tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK)  on ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
        WHERE ct.Type in ('AG', 'PH')
        and 
        not exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                    join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                    WHERE ca.Code in ('Z', 'W')
                    and ch.ID = @ID)
        and
        not exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                WHERE ca.Code in ('N', 'O')
                and ch.ID = @ID)
        and
        not exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                WHERE ca.Code in ('D', 'B')
                and ch.ID = @ID)
        and
        exists (SELECT * FROM tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                join tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) on ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                WHERE ca.Code in ('A', 'C')
                and ch.ID = @ID)
        and
        c.ID = @ID

IF (@cnt > 1)
    RETURN 'CATEGORY 2'

END
```

Comment: Just wondering... if you look at the execution plan for it, does it suggest that it has automatically optimised it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try combining both exists and non exists into one query and also only return `top 1`. This way you are minimizing the number of rows returned per `SELECT` statement within the `WHERE` clause. Also added `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to your proc this is a quick and easy way to gain some performance boost:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCaseType] @ID NUMERIC(18, 0)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @cnt INT;
        SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM   tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK)
             JOIN tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK) ON cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
             JOIN tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK) ON ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
        WHERE  ct.Type IN('AG', 'PH')
             AND NOT EXISTS
                        (SELECT *
                         FROM   tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                               JOIN tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) ON ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                         WHERE  ca.Code IN('Z', 'W')
                               AND ch.ID = @ID)
                         AND c.ID = @ID;
        IF(@cnt > 1)
           RETURN 'CATEGORY 1';
        SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM   tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK)
             JOIN tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK) ON cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
             JOIN tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK) ON ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
        WHERE  ct.Type IN('AG', 'PH')
             AND EXISTS
                     (SELECT TOP 1 1
                      FROM         tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                                JOIN tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) ON ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                      WHERE        ca.Code NOT IN('Z', 'W')
                                AND ca.Code IN('N', 'O')
                                AND ch.ID = @ID)
                      AND c.ID = @ID;
        IF(@cnt > 1)
           RETURN 'CATEGORY 2';
        SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM   tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK)
             JOIN tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK) ON cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
             JOIN tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK) ON ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
        WHERE  ct.Type IN('AG', 'PH')
             AND EXISTS
                     (SELECT TOP 1 1
                      FROM         tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                                JOIN tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) ON ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                      WHERE        ca.Code NOT IN('Z', 'W', 'N', 'O')
                                AND ca.Code IN('D', 'B')
                                AND ch.ID = @ID)
                      AND c.ID = @ID;
        IF(@cnt > 1)
           RETURN 'CATEGORY 2';
        SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM   tblCase c WITH (NOLOCK)
             JOIN tblDepartment cd WITH (NOLOCK) ON cd.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID
             JOIN tblType ct WITH (NOLOCK) ON ct.TypeID = cd.TypeID
        WHERE  ct.Type IN('AG', 'PH')
             AND EXISTS
                     (SELECT TOP 1 1
                      FROM         tblCharge ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                                JOIN tblAction ca WITH (NOLOCK) ON ch.ActionID = ca.ActionID
                      WHERE        ca.Code NOT IN('Z', 'W', 'N', 'O', 'D', 'B')
                                AND ca.Code IN('A', 'C')
                                AND ch.ID = @ID)
                      AND c.ID = @ID;
        IF(@cnt > 1)
           RETURN 'CATEGORY 2';
    END;
```

Comment: There's no need for `SELECT TOP 1` with `EXISTS`. SQL Server is smart enough to stop when it finds a single row that matches the criteria and it short-circuits it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If they're identical and if they're not correlated subqueries, then you can just save the results in a variable at the start of your stored procedure and then use that variable in the rest of your queries:

```
DECLARE
    @zw_exists    BIT = 0

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ... WHERE Code IN ('Z', 'W') AND CH.ID = @ID)
    @zw_exists = 1
```

Do the same for each type of query then just use the variable in your other queries.